# jQuery get html5 data value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a form with a quantity select dropdown and a buy now button.

```
<a href="#" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="75" data-product_sku="75" data-popup_id="popup_content_75" data-quantity="5" class="add_to_cart_button_popup button alt">Buy Now</a>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
<input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
<input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
<input type="button" value="+" class="plus"></div>
```

Now if a user select quantity 5 and click the buy now button it will display message like

```
{product title} 5X has been added to your order
```

Its working correctly. But when the user select another quantity (say 7 ) and click buy now its supposed to display message like

```
{product title} 7X has been added to your order
```

But it still showing the same `{product title} 5X has been added to your order` message.

Can someone tell me whats wrong.

This is my jQuery code.

```
 var quantity = $(this).data("quantity");
 $('span.itemcount').replaceWith(""+ quantity +" X");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).data("quantity")` is always from static `data-quantity="5"` where `this` is tag `A`

Answer (score 0):

> $(this).data("quantity")

will get data from the anchor

> A

tag which will be always 5. you need to get the value from

`<input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" ... />`

You can do that as follows

```
$(".input-text").value
```

Here is the code which updates the anchor code from your given link

```
// JavaScript source code
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    e(document).on("click", ".plus, .minus", function () {
        var t = e(this).closest(".quantity").find(".qty"),
            n = parseFloat(t.val()),
            r = parseFloat(t.attr("max")),
            i = parseFloat(t.attr("min")),
            s = t.attr("step");
        if (!n || n == "" || n == "NaN") n = 0;
        if (r == "" || r == "NaN") r = "";
        if (i == "" || i == "NaN") i = 0;
        if (s == "any" || s == "" || s == undefined || parseFloat(s) == "NaN") s = 1;
        e(this).is(".plus")
            ? r && (r == n || n > r) ? t.val(r) : t.val(n + parseFloat(s))
            : i && (i == n || n < i) ? t.val(i) : n > 0 && t.val(n - parseFloat(s));
        t.trigger("change");

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks. But that input is not dynamic. I mean if I increase the value of input button, the value actually changes in data-quantity. data-quantity attribute is defined in a href link button

Comment: It is possible that when you change the input button value, it doesn't reflect properly to the data-quantity attribute of href link. Can I see that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It works when I use like

```
 var quantityid = $(this).attr('id');
 var quantity = $("#" + quantityid + "").attr("data-quantity");
 $('span.itemcount').replaceWith(""+ quantity +" X");
```